# Could not found leave without an id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to update a leave form pending  status  of leave to approve in a dashbord controller.
I 'm  using rails 5.2 version. My controller code is

```
def leave_to_approve
@leave = Leave.find(params[:id])
status = params[:rejected].present? ? params[:rejected] : "Approved"
if leave.update_attribute("status",status)
  flash[:notice] = "Leave updated successfully"
end
```

end

view code

```
enter code <% @leaves.each_with_index do |leave, index| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= index + 1 %></td>
    <td><%= leave.leave_date %></td>
    <td><%= leave.leave_description %></td>
    <td><%= leave.status %></td>
    <td><%= link_to  'Approve', dashbord_leave_to_approve_path(leave),method: :put,class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %><td>
    <td><%= link_to "Reject", dashbord_leave_to_approve_path(leave), method: :put, class: "btn btn-large btn-danger" %><td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

routes code

```
get 'dashbord/leaves'
```

put 'dashbord/leave_to_approve'

Comment: How it is supposed you're passing the rejected param?

Comment: <%= link_to 'Reject', dashbord_leave_to_approve_path(leave, :rejected => "Rejected"), method: :put %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you change your links to this?

```
<%= link_to "Approve", dashbord_leave_to_approve_path(:id => leave.id, :approved=> "true"), method: :put, class: "btn btn-large btn-danger"  %>

<%= link_to "Reject", dashbord_leave_to_approve_path(:id => leave.id, :approved => "false"), method: :put, class: "btn btn-large btn-danger" %><td>
```

Do you get the `params[:id]`?
Can you access the `params[:approved]` flag?

Comment: I have leave controller through which i am submitted the leave in pending status, status="pending" but in dasboard controller i call all the leaves and admin should change the status of pending leave to approve or reject. But when i try above code it give error of undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @AhmedZain Sorry, I will have a look at my code and correct if I find something but could you please post the stack trace (log file entry) for the problem you are seeing in your question? It is very difficult to debug something without that. Does it tell you which line of code that error occurs on?

Comment: @leave = Leave.find(params[:leave][:id])

Comment: @AhmedZain Your params hash is empty. Looks like your link is not sending the leave object to the controller leave_to_approve method or the params are not what I expected them to be. Post up your stack trace in your original question and I'll correct my answer

Comment: http://localhost:3000/admin/dashboard/leave_to_approve.44?Rejected=Rejected

Comment: Id is passed in url from link

Comment: @AhmedZain your problem lies in the way you are submitting your params to the controller.

Comment: @AhmedZain Updated my answer

Comment: it give eroor of undefined local variable or method `leave_id' for #<#<Class:0x00007ff7026e4f78>:0x00007ff7026e3538>

Comment: I give you hole scenario. i emloyee/leaves controller through i set the status of status attribute="pending". In admin Dahboard controller i acess the all the leaves.In leaves.html.erb iclick the link to admin aprove the pending status to approve or reject

Comment: @AhmedZain I made a typo. It should be leave.id

Comment: @AhmedZain Just for future reference you should always look at your stack trace and post it in your question.

Comment: @AhmedZain, pleased you are getting somewhere